# unable to fetch set from map using java8

Tags: java, java-8

what I'm trying to do

```
Set<A> set=new HashSet();
Map<String,List<String>> map=new HashMap();
    if(map.keySet().contains("key"){
    for(String str: map.get("key")
    {
        for(A a : listOfA)
        {
            if(a.getString().equalsIgnoreCase(str);
            set.add(a);
        }
    }

    }
```

**What I tried**

```
if(map.keySet().contains("key")
{
    listOfA
    .stream()
     .filter(t->t.getString().equalsIgnoreCase(map.get("key")
                                               .stream
                                            .flatMap(c->c.toString()))
     .distinct()
     .collect(Collectors.toSet()):

}
```

> //error The method equalsIgnoreCase(String) in the type String is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Stream)

```
if(map.keySet().contains("key")
{
    map.get("key").stream().filter(t->t.equals(listOfA.stream().map(a->a.getString()))).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

**and this method returns Set<`String`>,obviously as output but I want Set<`A`> as output**

so how to solve this, using functional programming

Comment: The part with map and `"key"` seems redundant and a part of your wider problem, not the FP idiom you want.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  you got me let me post my actuall code

Comment: @MarkoTolpolink I added the real problem, to which I want to convert using java8

Comment: The "real" example is the same as the initial one in terms of structure. You can still eliminate `filterParams` and `"brand"` from this story.

Comment: Either way, getting the key set just for checking it for `contains` is redundant, you can use `map.containsKey()` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if any `String` of `map.get("key")` is `equalsIgnoreCase` to `getString()` of a given `A` instance by streaming `map.get("key")` and using `anyMatch` :

```
List<String> value = map.get("key");
Set<A> set = null;
if (value != null) {
   set = listOfA.stream()
                .filter(a->value.stream()
                                .anyMatch(s->a.getString().equalsIgnoreCase(s)))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: `map.get("key").stream()` can throw an NPE.

Comment: It would be simplest to eliminate `map.get("key")` from the story and write the piece of code that already assumes it's there. That's what I was trying to explain to OP.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Good suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: actually `NPE` is not an issue and thanks for the code . :)

Comment: i think i was missing `.anyMatch(..)` , Thanks again :)

Comment: You could use `map.getOrDefault("key", Collections.emptyList())`. Then you wouldn't need any special handling for the key being missing as none of the list would be added to the set.

Answer (score 2):

The following solution might scale better if your `listOfA` is rather large:

```
List<String> value = map.getOrDefault("key", Collections.emptyList());
Collection<String> c;
if(value.isEmpty()) c=value;
else { c=new TreeSet<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); c.addAll(value); }
Set<A> set = listOfA.stream()
                    .filter(a->c.contains(a.getString()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I tried your method but it is returning me empty collection, not sure why

Comment: Right, was a slip on my side. I thought I can create `c` as neat on-liner, but `TreeSet` has a constructor taking a comparator and a constructor taking an existing collection, but no constructor taking a comparator *and* an existing collection…

Comment: your previous solution had only one thing missing that you were passing empty collection and adding `c.addAll(value);` to previous solution is working fine :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not guarantied behavior. Calling `addAll` on `Collections.emptyList()` with an empty collection might do nothing (because iterating over the argument does noting), but it might also throw an exception (because the target collection is immutable). Whether such an eager check is made, is an implementation detail.